# ЧПУ с сортировкой по категориям

Tags: чпу

Подскажите как реализовать ЧПУ с вот таким вот видом `http://servera-minecraft.ru/servera-bez-whitelist-pirate-1.8-rossii.html` как видите на примере сайта. Я сразу подумал о explode но как тогда там работает day-z и tnt-run и прочие. Или может есть что то похожее. Я так и не смог найти даже маленького примера как это сделать.

Comment: что же это такое не кто не знает или лень одолела всех :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> что же это такое не кто не знает

А чего вы хотите? Чтоб кто-то обратился к их разработчикам и узнал для вас, как же они всё организовали? Сами понимаете, что никто это делать не будет. А способов это сделать, можно придумать массу. Вот самое первое, что пришло в голову:

```
$subject = array('servera-bez-whitelist-day-z-pirate-1.8-rossii'); 
$pattern = array('/servera/', '/bez-whitelist/','/day-z/', '/pirate/', '/1.8/', '/rossii/','/skyblock/'); 
$replace = array('servera', 'bezwhitelist', 'dayz', 'pirate', '1.8', 'rossii', 'skyblock');
print_r(preg_filter($pattern, $replace, $subject));
// результат:
Array
(
    [0] => servera-bezwhitelist-dayz-pirate-1.8-rossii
)
```

Но логичней уже заменять на идентификаторы:

```
/* ... */
$replace = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7');
/* ... */
// результат
Array
(
    [0] => 1-2-3-4-5-6
)
```

И на этом способы не заканчиваются. Приложите немного своих усилий и фантазии